# How does rails turn an activerecord object to a controller name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, polymorphism

I have an active record object  of type *I don't know* and I can do a link_to and rails somehow figures out what controller match.  Does anyone know how rails figures out what controller to use?

in my erb..

```
=link_to "who am I", rec_obj
```

It doesn't matter what the obj is (if it's an active record object), rails inspects it in some way and brings me to the correct controller, and thus the correct view screen for that object.

Does anyone know where I can find the code that runs which does the inspecting/reflection/what have you.

Why I need this.  rec_obj in my case is an inherited class and I want the base class controller to be called, not the inherited class controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [DOcumentation for link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), and click on Show Source. The code is pretty much self explanatory

Comment: Thanks.. that lead me down a rabbit hole that eventually led me to the code "route << RecordIdentifier.__send__("plural_class_name", record)" Which sort of makes me feel like inheritance isn't really an option for active record classes.  That saddens me. :(